# Why app is showing black space in iPad React Native

Tags: react-native, ipad, ios-simulator

I have designed a app in react native and it is working fine for IOS and android mobiles. but when I run it on the iPad it is showing app in the centre and black space of 2 inches in the border. App is showing too small all space covered by black. Can anybody tell me why it is happening?

Comment: Yes because the app has support for mobile apps and for iPad, you do have to manage it to provide the support for the iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change it in Xcode from build setting targeted set to 1,2 and it will resolve.

You have to change the Targeted device family. Select the project, then info-->Deployment--->Targeted device family to iPhone only and you have to do the same thing in targets. After that your app will be only for iPhone.